# Java: how to do fast copy of a BufferedImage's pixels? (unit test included)

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I want to do a copy (of a rectangle area) of the ARGB values from a source `BufferedImage` into a destination `BufferedImage`.  No compositing should be done: if I copy a pixel with an ARGB value of 0x8000BE50 (alpha value at 128), then the destination pixel must be *exactly* 0x8000BE50, totally overriding the destination pixel.

I've got a very precise question and I made a unit test to show what I need.  The unit test is fully functional and self-contained and is passing fine and is doing precisely what I want.

However, I want a **faster and more memory efficient** method to replace *copySrcIntoDstAt*(...).

That's the whole point of my question: I'm not after how to "fill" the image in a faster way (what I did is just an example to have a unit test).  All I want is to know what would be a *fast and memory efficient* way to do it (ie fast and not creating needless objects).

The proof-of-concept implementation I've made is obviously very memory efficient, but it is slow (doing one `getRGB` and one `setRGB` for every pixel).

Schematically, I've got this: (where A indicates corresponding pixels from the destination image before the copy)

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

And I want to have this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

where 'B' represents the pixels from the *src* image.

Note that I'm looking for an exact replacement of the *copySrcIntoDstAt(...)* method, not for an API link/quote.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class TestCopy {

    private static final int COL1 = 0x8000BE50;  // alpha at 128
    private static final int COL2 = 0x1732FE87;  // alpha at  23 

    @Test
    public void testPixelsCopy() {
        final BufferedImage src = new BufferedImage(  5,  5, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        final BufferedImage dst = new BufferedImage( 20, 20, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        convenienceFill( src, COL1 );
        convenienceFill( dst, COL2 );
        copySrcIntoDstAt( src, dst, 3, 4 );
        for (int x = 0; x < dst.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < dst.getHeight(); y++) {
                if ( x >= 3 && x <= 7 && y >= 4 && y <= 8 ) {
                    assertEquals( COL1, dst.getRGB(x,y) );
                } else {
                    assertEquals( COL2, dst.getRGB(x,y) );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // clipping is unnecessary
    private static void copySrcIntoDstAt(
            final BufferedImage src,
            final BufferedImage dst,
            final int dx,
            final int dy
    ) {
        // TODO: replace this by a much more efficient method
        for (int x = 0; x < src.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < src.getHeight(); y++) {
                dst.setRGB( dx + x, dy + y, src.getRGB(x,y) );
            }
        }
    }

    // This method is just a convenience method, there's
    // no point in optimizing this method, this is not what
    // this question is about
    private static void convenienceFill(
            final BufferedImage bi,
            final int color
    ) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
                bi.setRGB( x, y, color );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
private static void copySrcIntoDstAt(final BufferedImage src,
        final BufferedImage dst, final int dx, final int dy) {
    int[] srcbuf = ((DataBufferInt) src.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    int[] dstbuf = ((DataBufferInt) dst.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    int dstoffs = dx + dy * dst.getWidth();
    int srcoffs = 0;
    for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++ , dstoffs+= dst.getWidth(), srcoffs += width ) {
        System.arraycopy(srcbuf, srcoffs , dstbuf, dstoffs, width);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 very nice...  I never thought using several *System.arraycopy* would be the way to go. I take it that every BufferedImage always have a raster and that there's no object creation going on here right!?  It's really nice but at the same time it seems a bit weird: I'd have expected something pre-existing doing the job without having to do a *for* loop and System.arraycopy manually.  But, yup, really nice (just tried it btw and it seems fine :)

Comment: @WizardOfOds Thanks, you emphasized " faster and more memory efficient" some kind of loop is alwasy required to move offsets. Manipulation internal structures without doing copies and creating objects, I doubt that there would be a non JNI method that performs better.