# Why doesn't BufferedImage of type TYPE_INT_ARGB support the AlphaComposite.CLEAR rule?

Tags: java

When i do this:

```
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillRect(0,0,500,500);
```

regardless of the color red, a transparent black rectangle is drawn, and that is normal, because that's what the rule CLEAR does - transparent black.

However, when i do the same thing to a bufferedImage that has a type of "TYPE_INT_ARGB", it doesn't work

(type "TYPE_INT_BGR" works, but "ARGB" doesn't!)

does this have to do with a A (Alpha Channel) in the BufferedImage? How so? How do i use the rule CLEAR on ARGB type of BUfferedImage?

Comment: If it's transparent, how can it be black?

Comment: Specifically, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6297069/646634) in the duplicate.