# Set pixels of BufferedImage as transparent

Tags: java, swing, game-engine, bufferedimage, alpha

How can I quickly and efficiently set all pixels of a `BufferedImage` to transparent so that I can simply redraw what sprite graphics I want for each frame?

I am designing a simple game engine in java that updates a background and foreground `BufferedImage` and draws them to a composite `VolatileImage` for efficient scaling, to be drawn to a `JPanel`.  This scalable model allows me to add more layers and iterate over each drawing layer.

I simplified my application into one class given below that demonstrates my issue.  Use the arrow keys to move a red square over the image.  The challenge is I want to decouple updating the game graphics from drawing the composite graphics to the game engine. I have studied seemingly thorough answers to this question but cannot figure out how to apply them to my application:

- [Java: Filling a BufferedImage with transparent pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672697/java-filling-a-bufferedimage-with-transparent-pixels)

Here is the critical section that does not clear the pixels correctly.  The commented out section is from stack-overflow answers I have read already, but they either draw the background as a non-transparent black or white.  I know the `foregroundImage` begins with transparent pixels in my implementation as you can see the random pixel noise of the `backgroundImage` behind the red sprite when the application begins.  Right now, the image is not cleared, so the previous drawn images remain.

```
/** Update the foregroundGraphics. */
private void updateGraphics(){
    Graphics2D fgGraphics = (Graphics2D) foregroundImage.getGraphics(); 

    // set image pixels to transparent
    //fgGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
    //fgGraphics.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    //fgGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //fgGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));

    // draw again.
    fgGraphics.setColor(Color.RED);
    fgGraphics.fillRect(sx, sy, spriteSize, spriteSize);
    fgGraphics.dispose();
}
```

Here is my entire example code:

```
/**
 * The goal is to draw two BufferedImages quickly onto a scalable JPanel, using 
 * a VolatileImage as a composite.
 */
public class Example extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener
{   
    private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int                 width;
    private int                 height;
    private Object              imageLock;
    private Random              random;
    private JFrame              frame;
    private Container           contentPane;
    private BufferedImage       backgroundImage;
    private BufferedImage       foregroundImage;
    private VolatileImage       compositeImage;
    private Graphics2D          compositeGraphics;
    private int[]               backgroundPixels;
    private int[]               foregroundPixels;
    // throttle the framerate.
    private long                prevUpdate; 
    private int                 frameRate;
    private int                 maximumWait;
    // movement values.
    private int speed;
    private int sx;
    private int sy;
    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int spriteSize;

    /** Setup required fields. */
    public Example(){
        width = 512;
        height = 288;
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        imageLock = new Object();
        random = new Random();
        frame = new JFrame("BufferedImage Example");
        frame.addKeyListener(this);
        contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
        // used to create hardware-accelerated images.
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
        backgroundImage = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height,Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        foregroundImage = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height,Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        compositeImage = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage(width, height,Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        compositeGraphics = compositeImage.createGraphics();
        compositeGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        compositeGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        backgroundPixels = ((DataBufferInt) backgroundImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        foregroundPixels = ((DataBufferInt) foregroundImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();     
        //initialize the background image.
        for(int i = 0; i < backgroundPixels.length; i++){
            backgroundPixels[i] = random.nextInt();
        }
        // used to throttle frames per second
        frameRate = 180;
        maximumWait = 1000 / frameRate;
        prevUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // used to update sprite state.
        speed = 1;
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
        sx = 0;
        sy = 0;     
        spriteSize = 32;
    }

    /** Renders the compositeImage to the Example, scaling to fit. */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // draw the composite, scaled to the JPanel.
        synchronized (imageLock) {
            ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(compositeImage, 0, 0, super.getWidth(), super.getHeight(), 0, 0, width, height, null);
        }
        // force repaint.
        repaint();
    }

    /** Update the BufferedImage states. */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            updateSprite();
            updateGraphics();
            updateComposite();
            throttleUpdateSpeed();
        }
    }

    /** Update the Sprite's position. */
    private void updateSprite(){
        // update the sprite state from the inputs.
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;         
        if (Command.UP.isPressed()) dy -= speed;
        if (Command.DOWN.isPressed()) dy += speed;
        if (Command.LEFT.isPressed()) dx -= speed;
        if (Command.RIGHT.isPressed()) dx += speed;
        sx += dx;
        sy += dy;
        // adjust to keep in bounds.
        sx = sx < 0 ? 0 : sx + spriteSize >= width ? width - spriteSize : sx;
        sy = sy < 0 ? 0 : sy + spriteSize >= height ? height - spriteSize : sy;
    }

    /** Update the foregroundGraphics. */
    private void updateGraphics(){
        Graphics2D fgGraphics = (Graphics2D) foregroundImage.getGraphics(); 

        // set image pixels to transparent
        //fgGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
        //fgGraphics.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 255));
        //fgGraphics.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        //fgGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));

        // draw again.
        fgGraphics.setColor(Color.RED);
        fgGraphics.fillRect(sx, sy, spriteSize, spriteSize);
        fgGraphics.dispose();
    }

    /** Draw the background and foreground images to the volatile composite. */
    private void updateComposite(){
        synchronized (imageLock) {
            compositeGraphics.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
            compositeGraphics.drawImage(foregroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }

    /** Keep the update rate around 60 FPS. */
    public void throttleUpdateSpeed(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Math.max(0, maximumWait - (System.currentTimeMillis() - prevUpdate)));
            prevUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Ignore key typed events. */
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    /** Handle key presses. */
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        setCommandPressedFrom(e.getKeyCode(), true);
    }

    /** Handle key releases. */
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        setCommandPressedFrom(e.getKeyCode(), false);
    }

    /** Switch over key codes and set the associated Command's pressed value. */
    private void setCommandPressedFrom(int keycode, boolean pressed){
        switch (keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            Command.UP.setPressed(pressed);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            Command.DOWN.setPressed(pressed);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            Command.LEFT.setPressed(pressed);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            Command.RIGHT.setPressed(pressed);
            break;
        }
    }
    /** Commands are used to interface with key press values. */
    public enum Command{
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;      
        private boolean pressed;

        /** Press the Command. */
        public void press() {
            if (!pressed) pressed = true;
        }
        /** Release the Command. */
        public void release() {
            if (pressed) pressed = false;
        }       
        /** Check if the Command is pressed. */
        public boolean isPressed() {
            return pressed;
        }       
        /** Set if the Command is pressed. */
        public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
            if (pressed) press();
            else release();
        }
    }

    /** Begin the Example. */
    public void start(){
        try {           
            // create and display the frame.
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Example e = new Example();
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });         
            // start updating from key inputs.
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();          
        }
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /** Start the application. */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example e = new Example();
        e.start();
    }   
}
```

*Edits:*

*- Fixed a typo in the for-loop initializing the `backgroundPixels` to random.*

Comment: 1) I suspect (but have not tested) that the answer might be in methods concerned with the complete raster of the (initial, entirely blank) image.  For that, see [`BufferedImage.getRaster()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRaster--) and [`setData(Raster)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setData-java.awt.image.Raster-). 2) The top answer to that linked question mentions using data arrays of `int[]` to store the state of a blank image & restore it. 3) `new BufferedImage(..)` (make a new one).  ...

Comment: ... I'd test those three methods first, profiling them against one another, in search of an answer.  But then, I might also be completely wrong, so I'm not going to venture an actual 'answer' as yet.  ;)

Comment: OK.. those 4, counting the suggestion of @MadProgrammer.  Hey, you're not going to know till testing them.

Comment: I figured it out, I accidentally used `drawRect()` instead of `fillRect()` when trying to clear the background.  I noticed as there was a 1 pixel transparent barrier when I was playing with the commented out code.  See my answer if curious ...

Answer (score 6):

Turns out I goofed in my method selection.  I noticed I was clearing a one-pixel wide box that was the outline of my graphics.  This is because I accidentally used `drawRect()` instead of `fillRect()`.  Upon changing my code it works now.  Here are examples I was able to get to work.

Example using `AlphaComposite.CLEAR` (draw with any opaque color):

```
    // clear pixels
    fgGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
    fgGraphics.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,255));
    fgGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    fgGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));
    // draw new graphics
```

Example using `AlphaComposite.SRC_OUT` (draw with any color with alpha zero):

```
    // clear pixels
    fgGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OUT));
    fgGraphics.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,0));
    fgGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    fgGraphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));
    // draw new graphics
```

Comment: Forgive me for laughing, but I do this all the time as well ;)

Comment: I know, its usually always a simple mistake.  All I had to do is go through the motions of carefully duplicating what logic I needed for the most basic, simple example to find the error.  That's coding.

Comment: *"All I had to do is go through the motions of carefully duplicating what logic I needed for the most basic, simple example to find the error."*  If more programmers could learn from that sage advice you just served up, I suspect people like me and @MadProgrammer would have a lot fewer questions to answer.  In fact there are at least a couple of questions I was intending to put to the SO minds and in preparing a simple example, discovered and solved the problem.  Glad you got that problem sorted.  :)