# awtrobot reads incorrect colors

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard, awtrobot

I'm looking for a platform-independent way to read colors from the screen and simulate user input through mouse and keyboard actions. I have previously been using `java.awt.robot`, however some time in the past 2 years it has started reporting incorrect colors in OSX (other operating systems appear to get accurate colors) as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519523/bufferedimage-createscreencapture-produces-wrong-colors).

I'm looking for either a workaround for this bug or any other library/language which will provide this functionality.

Using the fairly simple code below can demonstrate the issue.

```
public void printColorAtCoordinate(int x, int y)
{
    Color color;
    color = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);
    System.out.println("RGB: " + Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB()));
}
```

It appears to get some colors correct, such as `0x000000`, `0xffffff`, `0x0000ff`, `0xff0000` but not others such as `0x00ff00`, which it reports as `ff22ff00` (instead of `ff00ff00`). Most colors are off by at least a small amount.

Comment: I'm also seeing this.  I think it may be due to color profiles, possibly Java.awt.robot reads color values without looking at the profile.